# Проблема с AJAX и Apache2

Tags: php, ajax, apache, apache2

Здравствуйте. Приходится выполнять довольно длительный -- несколько десятков секунд -- AJAX запрос к серверу на Apache2. Проблема заключается в том, что если закрыть страницу до завершения запроса, то при попытке зайти на любую страницу сайта приходится ждать довольно долго ответа от сервера. Видимо, скрипт на сервере продолжает выполняться. Можно ли как-то принудительно завершать процесс на сервере при закрытии страницы в браузере?

Comment: вы ищете ответ на неправильно поставленный вопрос. И да, можно, для этого вам придется написать js, который будет при закрытии страницы делать запрос к серверу, а на сервер-сайде вам придется писать код, который будет убивать нужный процесс по айди, который прислал js. Это все в корне неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша функция влияет на работу сервера и других клиентов и это очень пагубно сказывается на производительности вашего сайта. Вам требуется ее оптимизировать.

По умолчанию в PHP, скрипт завершает свою работу при отключении клиента, т.е отсутствует удаленный браузер, которому адресован весь вывод.

За игнорирование отключение клиента отвечает опция ignore_user_abort в конфигурационном файле php.ini или php_value ignore_user_abort в конфигурационном файле Apache httpd.conf.

Правда, к этому есть одно замечание, о том что PHP не сможет определить обрыв пользователем соединения пока не будет произведена попытка отправки информации клиенту. Простое использование выражения echo не гарантирует отправку информации. Тут нужно пользоваться функцией flush.